# How to swich from depricated code while using get_duplicates()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to upgrade pandas code before it deprecates. The goal is to check whether there are duplicate IDs and then select the rows of said IDs.
The IDs are set as the index of my_data (the pandas Dataframe I am working with).
The following code:

```
dups = my_data.index.get_level_values('ID').get_duplicates()
```

returns the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: 'get_duplicates' is deprecated and will be removed in a    future release. You can use idx[idx.duplicated()].unique() instead
"""Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

And then when I run:

```
duplicates = my_data.loc[dups]
```

It returns a pandas Dataframe containing all the duplicates on the ID level (which is my end goal).

From my understanding, there is no method or attribute to **pandas.Dataframe** that is called idx. 
I tried using the following:

```
dups = pd.Index(my_data).duplicated()
```

it returns a numpy ndarray containing bool values which I was unable to use later to load the duplicate rows in a separate DataFrame.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with keep=False for return mask for dupes, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
my_data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[ 4,0,0,10,0,0],
                        'B':[ 0,2,0,0,0,0],
                        'ID':list('aabdcd')}).set_index(['ID','A'])


print (my_data)
       B
ID A    
a  4   0
   0   2
b  0   0
d  10  0
c  0   0
d  0   0


dups = my_data.index.get_level_values('ID').duplicated(keep=False)
duplicates = my_data[dups]
print (duplicates)
       B
ID A    
a  4   0
   0   2
d  10  0
   0   0
```